# problem when install qt4: no rule to make target "install-strip"

Tags: linux, qt4

when I finished compiling qt4,  I typed gmake install-strip 
but it doesn't work either it says" no rule to make target "install-strip"
how to solve this problem? Whether I should add some configure options?

Comment: Have you looked inside the Makefile to see what the option's called? qt4's makefile may not ship with that option defined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do a **make install** , it will strip release-mode libraries itself automatically.